# WordPress If statement Feature Image

Tags: wordpress, image, if-statement, statements, wordpress-featured-image

What I am trying to achieve is for posts that haven't set a featured image to use the default CSS background-image . That means every post will have an image.

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') ); ?>
 <div class="entry-header featureImg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url ?>')"></div>
```

Basically here is the thing :

```
<div class="entry-header featureImg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url ?>')">
```

for post without featured image set the 'background-image' should be the default one from CSS because as the code is actually written the bg image for those posts(whitout feat image set) is :

```
background-image: url(''); //taken from page source
```

this should be done with php if statements but I have no idea how to work with this syntax :

```
`<?php if($has_post_thumbnail) : ?>

  <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID,'thumbnail') ); ?>
<div class="entry-header featureImg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url ?>')">

<?php else : ?>

    <div class="entry-header featureImg">

<?php endif; ?>
?>`
```

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin for this instead? https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: @MichaelDoye I don't want plugins, I am building a new theme - I am sure that this can be done very easily with if statements but I don't handle this this so good ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you just need to use the `if` statement on whether or not to show the *whole* style tag or not.  It's cleaner to add these sort of things to your `functions.php` file though so if you add this there:

```
function alternative_bg_img() {
  global $post;
  if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    var $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'thumbnail ') );
    echo 'style="background-image:url(' + $image + ');';
  }
}
```

And then add:

```
<div class="entry-header featureImg" <?php alternative_bg_img(); ?>>
```

Then the whole `style` tag (not just the image) will only appear if you there is a featured image.

Comment: Hmmm...if I replace `<div class="entry-header featureImg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url ?>')">` with your code `<div class="entry-header featureImg" <?php alternative_bg_img(); ?>>` the default image is showing even on those posts that have set an image.

Comment: echo 'style="background-image:url(' . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'thumbnail ') ) . "');"; It's not Javascript so use period to concatenate. Plus will convert to number.

Comment: @bobdye if I replace your code with RichieAHB's code the featured images causing a lot of mess on the page ... not sure why.

Comment: @Hann try now - didn't check my quotes properly.